# @PropertyKey Annotation is not working with Kotlin but with Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin, annotations

When i add a new properties file to my project inside resources and name it as for example "lang1" than the BUNDLE_NAME is recognized correctly.

But if i add an ResourceBundle containing lang2_de and lang2_en and try to use its base name as BUNDLE_NAME it shows me the following error "Invalid resource bundle reference 'lang2'.

So i basically have 3 files.

1. lang1_de.properties
2. lang2_de.properties
3. lang2_en.properties

lang2 is bundled into an Resource Bundle with "'base name' = lang2"

This is working with kotlin:

```
private const val BUNDLE_NAME = "lang1"

fun foo(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = BUNDLE_NAME) key: String): String {
    return key
}
```

This is not:

```
private const val BUNDLE_NAME = "lang2"

fun foo(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = BUNDLE_NAME) key: String): String {
    return key
}
```

But if i do the same thing with java it is working ...

```java
private static final String BUNDLE_NAME = "lang2";

public static void foo(@PropertyKey(resourceBundle = BUNDLE_NAME) String key) {
    return key;
}
```

I am doing this for getting the information about my properties being used inside my code.

The properties are marked correctly inside the property files for both examples.

But for lang2 the strings used inside the code are all shown with inspection error "String literal 'testprop' doesn't appear to be valid property key ..."

I also created a issue for that inside the JetBrains/java-annotations:
https://github.com/JetBrains/java-annotations/issues/13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report, the bug was submitted at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-31359, please [follow it for updates](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241135).